# Android: How to get the event when checkbox in ListView is clicked?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new to Android, I am trying to do a simple application where in I have to display a list of contacts available in phonebook in a ListView in the application, I am tryring to add checkbox t each item. When the user checks the checkbox, I want to retrive the item. So far, I am able to display the list but its unclear how to check for the checkbox check event.

My code is as follows:

XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/android:list" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" android:clickable="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id ="@+id/savebutton"
    android:text = "save"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/android:list" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" android:clickable="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id ="@+id/savebutton"
    android:text = "save"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Source Code:

```
public class testcontacts extends ListActivity 
{
    private ListAdapter adapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //CheckBox box = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        //box.setFocusable(false);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter
        (this, R.layout.contact_entry, cur,new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});   
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the getCheckedItemPosition method to get the position of the item that is checked.Once you have the position,you can use the findViewById to retrieve the item and the isChecked method to check. 
Here's an example :

```
     int pos = list.getCheckItemPosition(); //list being a ListView previously defined
     //Look for the checked CheckBox in the particular position
     CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(pos);
     if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
     //Do something here
 }
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the Postion of the item checked

```
.getCheckedItemPositions()
```

Comment: Hello Soorya,Thanks for your reply, but how do I catch the events? How do I get to know when a checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

In listView onclick item.
Do it like this..

```
 CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxXML);
```

this checkbox will have same state as of clicked listitem checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

To create an event that listen to click events on the listview items you can try this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)view;
              textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked());
              switchAlarm(textView.isChecked(),position);
          }
        });
```

This code will change the chacked state of the item.

I hope it helps.